# Plotting logarithmic values in separate graphs

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot (log ϵ vs log δt) and (log ϵ vs log δS) on two separate graphs in MATLAB. Can anyone help me with the algorithm for achieving this? ϵ is an error term, δS is change in stock price and δt is change in time.

Comment: Please don't edit the question in such a way that it becomes a completely different question. That yields any existing answers invalid. If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Link to this one if necessary. Editing should be used to make a question more clear, or otherwise improve a post. I undid your edit, as it's against the policies of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose:

```
err = rand(100,1);
dt = logspace(0,4,100);
ds = logspace(0,3,100);
```

To plot those values on a log-log scale, simply use the [`loglog`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html) command

```
loglog(dt, err) %% Plots error vs dt
loglog(ds, err) %% Plots error vs. ds
```

Or, if you only want a logarithmic x-axis use [`semi-log scale`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html):

```
semilogx(dt, err)
semilogx(ds, err)
```

If you want to have two plots open at the same time in two different windows, you may use [`figure`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/figure.html), like this:

```
loglog(dt, err) %% Plots error vs dt
figure
loglog(ds, err) %% Plots error vs. ds
```

If you want to have two plots in the same window, but in two different frames, you can use [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-graph-with-subplots.html) this way:

```
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
loglog(dt, err)
title('err / dt')

subplot(1,2,2)
loglog(ds, err)
title('err / ds')
```

[image]

The figure above was created using the code:

```
err = exp(0.005.*(1:100)).*rand(100,1)';
dt = logspace(0,4,100);
ds = logspace(0,4,100);

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
loglog(dt, err)
title(['\epsilon / \delta' 't'])
xlabel(['\delta' 't'])
ylabel('\epsilon')

subplot(1,2,2)
loglog(ds, err)
title(['\epsilon / \delta' 's'])
xlabel(['\delta' 's'])
ylabel('\epsilon')
```